# Merge Sort C++11 C++17

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, mergesort, c++17

**Question**

Any way I can optimize this further using new C++11 or C++17 features? Would also like feedback on my variable naming, memory management, and style (notice my placement of `varible_name++` in some areas), and how I've abstracted the sort into a `recursive_merge_sort` function and a `merge` function.

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>

void merge(int* data, int low, int mid, int high)
{
    int low_copy = low;
    int mid_copy = mid;

    int size = high - low;
    int* sorted = new int[size];
    int i = 0;

    while(low_copy < mid && mid_copy < high) {
        if(data[low_copy] < data[mid_copy]) {
            sorted[i] = data[low_copy++];
        }
        else {
            sorted[i] = data[mid_copy++];
        }
        ++i;
    }

    while(low_copy < mid) {
        sorted[i++] = data[low_copy++];
    }
    while(mid_copy < high) {
        sorted[i++] = data[mid_copy++];
    }

    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        data[low + i] = sorted[i];
    }
}

void recursive_merge_sort(int* data, int low, int high) {
    if(low >= high - 1) { return; }

    int mid = (high + low) / 2;
    recursive_merge_sort(data, low, mid);
    recursive_merge_sort(data, mid, high);

    merge(data, low, mid, high);
}

void merge_sort(int* data, int num_elements) {
    recursive_merge_sort(data, 0, num_elements);
}

int main()
{
    int data[] = { 5, 1, 4, 3, 65, 6, 128, 9, 0 };
    int num_elements = 9;

    std::cout << "unsorted\n";
    for(int i=0; i < num_elements; ++i) {
        std::cout << data[i] << " ";
    }

    merge_sort(data, num_elements);

    std::cout << "\nsorted\n";
    for(int i=0; i < num_elements; ++i) {
        std::cout << data[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not much different from C, and there is a memory leak. Perhaps you could use a tool such as valgrind to detect memory leak and have a look at [classic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24650627/4593721) on implementation of sorting algorithms?

Comment: This becomes much more interesting when you are sorting something not as trivial as `int`. Because C++ allows you to define the `operator<` for any type you can sort any type that can be compared.

Comment: Did you calculate how much memory your code allocates during sorting, say, a one thousand elements array? And how many times it invokes allocator function?

Comment: I attempted to use valgrind, but ran into this issue on my OS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52732036/how-to-install-valgrind-on-macos-mojave10-14-with-homebrew

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Design

Passing `data` with `high` and `low` works. But is equivalent to `data+low` and `data+high`. And just passing two values.

This is what is referred to as an Iterator range. If you look at the standard library you will see that a lot of the concepts hinge around iterators you should look that up and understand how it works.

#### Code Review

For every call to `new` there should be a call to `delete`.

```
    int* sorted = new int[size];
```

Or so the old text books tell us. In modern C++ you probably should never call new or delete (unless you know its a good idea).

But here you are leaking memory because you don't release it. You should add a `delete [] sorted;` to the end of the function.

**BUT** leaving the new/delete in your code is not a good idea. It's not exception safe to start with. So simply declare a `vector<int>` here and let it manage the memory for you.

We should also note that memory management is very expensive. So rather than doing this every loop. Why not do it once at the beginning and reuse the memory.

Sure this works:

```
    while(low_copy < mid && mid_copy < high) {
        if(data[low_copy] < data[mid_copy]) {
            sorted[i] = data[low_copy++];
        }
        else {
            sorted[i] = data[mid_copy++];
        }
        ++i;
    }
```

But we could simplify it:

```
     for(;low_copy < mid && mid_copy < high; ++i) {
        sorted[i] = (data[low_copy] < data[mid_copy])
                       ? data[low_copy++];
                       : data[mid_copy++];
    }
```

Also when you see loops like this you should look at the standard algorithms to see if there is one that will do all that work for you.

Another thing to note is that you are copying the value from `data` to `sorted`. This is fine for integers, but you should be able to sort nearly any C++ type and copying a C++ type is not usually the most efficient way to get the value from one location to another. You should look up the concept of `moving`. When the type being sorted is a bit more complex moving it (rather than copying is usually a better idea).

These loops can definitely be done by standard algorthims:

```
    while(low_copy < mid) {
        sorted[i++] = data[low_copy++];
    }
    // Or 
    std::copy(data + low_copy, data + mid, sorted + i);
    // Or (when you move objects)
    std::move(data + low_copy, data + mid, sorted + i);
```

This is subject to overflow.

```
    int mid = (high + low) / 2;
```

Common mistake. If `high` and `low` are both large then this could easily overflow. Do the division fist (on the difference). Then add to the low.

```
    int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
```

Are you sure there are 9 elements?

```
    int data[] = { 5, 1, 4, 3, 65, 6, 128, 9, 0 };
    int num_elements = 9;
```

Common source of errors. Don't manually do stuff the compiler can work out correctly. This is especially true if `data` is subsequently modified (and human person can make mistakes) does not change `num_elements`.

```
    int data[] = { 5, 1, 4, 3, 65, 6, 128, 9, 0 };
    int num_elements = sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]);
```

In more modern versions of C++ we even have a standard way of doing it:

```
    int num_elements = std::size(data);
```

No need for this in main:

```
    return 0;
```

Comment: For your `std::copy` example, why did you choose to add to the pointers instead of using `var.begin()` and `var.end()`? This must be an example of an Iterator range.

Comment: How did you determine what calculation you use for mid to over overflow here `  int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;`?

Comment: @greg: The `std::copy()` example is an example of replacing your `where(){}` loop. So it should use the same range.

Comment: @greg: How did I work out out how to calculate the mid point in a range? Or how did I determine that `high + low` could overflow?

Comment: @greg Please write comments in sentences. I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: How did you rearrange my equation to account for overflow?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93021/discussion-between-martin-york-and-greg).

Comment: Pointer iterator syntax is explained here https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/pointers-arrays

Comment: @greg Note pointers are an implementation of the iterator concept.

Answer (score 3):

1. If you have a range from start till end, why do you describe it with a base-pointer and two indices, instead of two pointers or a pointer and a size?
   Equivalently for the split range passed to `merge()`.
2. You are allocating a new array on each call to `merge()`.
   Why not just do a single allocation in the base `merge_sort()`?
3. Also, you are leaking it.
4. Using the ternary operator `condition ? true_expr : false_expr` would simplify some of your code.
5. `return 0;` is implicit for `main()`.

That should be enough to get you started.